# How do I have to understand the values in the Votes Cast section in my profile?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, voting, profile-page

Today I visited my profile page and saw the *Votes Cast* section as shown below:

[image: Screenshot of my Votes Cast section]

The values in the **month & week columns** were showing **9 & 27**, respectively. I understand these values as time periods since when I casted the votes (if I am not wrong).

But I have joined Meta just 14 days ago. So, why are the columns showing 9 months and 27 weeks if my understanding about them is not wrong? Is my understanding correct? If not, please correct me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The start of the month is less than two days ago.  The start of this week was more than 4 days ago.

All of your votes from the 29th through the 31st are counted in this week's count, but not this month's count.

Comment: Sorry, but i didn't get you..

Comment: @choxx week/month reflect the time since the since the start of the week, and the start of the month, not the past 7/30 days respectively.

Comment: That means in last month i did 9 vote cast and by week it is 27(if I am getting it correct?)

Comment: @choxx *This* month you've cast 9 votes, and *this* week you've cast 27 votes.  Not *last* month/week.

Comment: One more thing I would like to ask you. I am thinking that the title of the question is not appropriate. Should I change that!?

Comment: @choxx If you can think of a better title, go ahead.